# How to write javascript value in css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I want to write the javascript value in css file.so below is my requirement.

```
jsp file:
        $(document).ready(function(){
             var isRedirectionURL = '#{ceproperties['REDIRECTION_URL']}';
        });

css file: (style.css) 
@font-face{
font-family:'weblysleeknormal';
src:url("'+isRedirectionURL+'/tdhost/weblysleekuisl.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

so here i want the javascript variable "isRedirectionURL" dynamic value should replace in css file to src:url("'+isRedirectionURL+'/tdhost/weblysleekuisl.ttf") format("truetype");

Please help me how to resolve this?

Comment: Please rephrase this question.  You are looking to dynamically change the value of a variable, or placeholder, in your CSS file?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to files on the client side. The easiest thing to do here would be to append a style tag to the DOM and add those style declarations to it.

Comment: Please tell me how to do it?